# AutoComplete="off" is inconsistent

Tags: asp.net, autocomplete

I have a website where a user can login from two different pages. I have set AutoComplete = "OFF" for the username and password textboxes in both the pages. But, surprisingly, autocompletion is disabled only in one page.!!! The other page still gives previous username suggestions.Is this feature really consistent? I have double checked hundred times. I'm doing no syntax error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29582380/4462191 duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your browser or a plugin isn't configured to do that, above and beyond the browser's default behavior.  Some password management features/plugins look deceptively similar to the browser's traditional autocompletion history, but are out of your markup's control.

Comment: I agree some features could be out of markup's control. But it works in one page and not in other under the same website. How can that be?

Answer (score 0):

How are you turning Autocomplete off?  Have you tried

```
$("#yourSelector").autocomplete("destroy");
```